# Excel: Copy and Paste using Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets ("Input" and "History"). 
The idea is as follows:

1. Anybody can fill in data in "Input" sheet
2. Macro will copy data from "Input" to "History"
3. Copied data should not override previous entries
4. Data in "Input" sheet should be cleared so that new entries could be added

This seems to be easy, but the challenge is to copy data to the next empty row in sheet "History" (e.g., copy cells A1 and A2 from "Input" to B1 and C1 if they are empty, or B2 and C2 if previous row already has data and so on down).

Comment: Test the target cell before pasting : isblank() or istext etc....then row +1 ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Input").Range("A1:A2").Copy
Worksheets("History").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```